# how to create customized frequency table in SAS

Tags: sas

Assume I have a data called orig with variable x and s, s being binary as follows:

```
x  s
12 1
3  0
3  0
34 1  
12 0
```

I want to create a new table or data which will be similar to the frequency table of orig. The first column will be the variables appeared in x, the second column will be the number of s variable "1" for those x, and third column will be the number of "0" and last one will be the total number of x. If we use the above table as an example the 
new table I am expecting is :

```
x    "0 of s"    "1 of s"   total
3      1          1         2
12     1          1         2
34     0          1         1
```

Comment: Shouldn't your table display 2 for the intersection of x=3 and "0 of s" and a 0 for x=3 and "1 of s"?

Comment: Yes, sorry the typo.

Comment: Do you need a table or just the output in the display?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward in `proc sql`. Use a `group by` statement and `sum` summary functions that evaluate to `1` if an expression is true, and `0` if it is not.

```
proc sql;
create table newtable as
select
  x,
  sum(s=0) '0 of s',
  sum(s=1) '1 of s',
  sum(1) as total
from orig
group by x;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. For your x=3 output, I think you want "0 of s"=2, "1 of s"=0, though, in order to be consistent with the original dataset that you gave.

```
data orig;
        input x s;
        datalines;
12 1
3  0
3  0
34 1
12 0
;

proc print data=orig;
        title 'Original Dataset';
run;

proc sort data=orig;
        by x;
run;

data orig_collapsed;
        set orig;
        retain s0 s1;
        by x;

        if first.x then do;
                s0=0;
                s1=0;
        end;


        if s=0 then s0=s0+1;
        if s=1 then s1=s1+1;

        if last.x then do;
                total = s0 + s1;
                output;
        end;

        keep x s0 s1 total;
run;

proc print data=orig_collapsed noobs;
        title 'Collapsed Dataset';
run;
```